# Inferring types from string literals in unions

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Let's say I want to manage services from different modules in a project within a single function, and depending on the type of data I get, I call a different service.

For example, I've got these two DTOs:

```
class UserDto {
  constructor (name: string) {
      this.name = name
  }
  public name: string;
}

class CarDto {
  constructor (brand: string) {
      this.brand = brand
  }
  public brand: string;
}
```

And these two Services:

```
class UserService {
  create(val: UserDto) {
    // Create the user
    return 'foo';
  }
}

class CarService {
  create(val: CarDto) {
    // Create the car
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Pretty basic stuff. Then I can get a service that can manage the calls depending on what type of data I get. For that, I create a union type that is supposed to figure out what kind of data I'm getting and what service I should call, let's say something like this:

```
type DataType =
  | {
      data: 'user';
      dto: UserDto;
      service: 'userService'
    }
  | {
      data: 'car';
      dto: CarDto;
      service: 'carService'
    }
```

Finally I want to put this all together in a function within the service that manages these two sub-services, like this:

```
class MainService {
  constructor (
    private userService: UserService,
    private carService: CarService,
  ) {}

  serviceManager(val: DataType) {
   // Call the right service here!
  }
}
```

What I don't want to do is checking for every property if that's the one I want. **This is what I'd like to avoid**:

```
serviceManager(val: DataType) {
   const name = val.data;
    if (name === 'user') this.userService.create(val.dto);
  }
```

Instead, I would prefer an approach in which TypeScript would infer what service I get and what information I'm passing to said service. So this is what *I thought* should work (spoiler, it doesn't):

```
serviceManager(val: DataType) {
   const func = this[val.service];
    func.create(val.dto);
    // Argument of type 'UserDto | CarDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserDto & CarDto'.
    // Type 'UserDto' is not assignable to type 'UserDto & CarDto'.
    // Property 'brand' is missing in type 'UserDto' but required in type 'CarDto'.
  }
```

Finally, I decided to go for another route and don't even use subservices. But I have been trying to find a workaround to this problem even if it's not relevant for the project I'm working on anymore.

Would it be possible to make something like this with TypeScript with some different way of declaring the type DataType or is it just plain impossible? Maybe I should have used generics when declaring the functions within the subservices?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbar4N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I beileive it does, although I'm not quite used to generics, so I'm having a little bit of trouble when trying to call the serviceManager function, so if you could also add it to your answer, I'd be really glad. Otherwise, I'm still very thankful!

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYl1rm)?  I will write up an answer either way, but let me know if that does or does not resolve the trouble with calling the `serviceManager()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't directly support what I call "correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)".  Inside your implementation of `serviceManager()`, the `val` parameter is of the union type `DataType`.  Thus `this[val.service]` and `val.dto` are also of union types (`UserService | CarService` and `UserDto | CarDto`, respectively).  But TypeScript doesn't realize and cannot track that these unions are "correlated" in such a way that, for example, if `this[val.service]` is of type `UserService` then `val.dto` will be of type `UserDto`.  The compiler thinks maybe `this[val.service]` will be of type `UserService` while `val.dto` will be of type `CarDto`.  And you get an error.  This general problem is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The recommended approach to deal with this is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Instead of using correlated unions, your code should be refactored to use some basic key-value mapping types, and [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) these types, and generic indexes into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over these types.  For your code I would be inclined to refactor it this way:

```
interface DtoMap {
  user: UserDto,
  car: CarDto
}

type ServiceMap =
  { [K in keyof DtoMap]: { create(val: DtoMap[K]): string } }

type DataType<K extends keyof DtoMap> = { [P in K]:
  { data: P, dto: DtoMap[P] }
}[K]
```

The `DtoMap` type is the "basic key-value mapping type" you need, which maps from the `data` property of your intended `DataType` union, to the corresponding DTO type.

Then `ServiceMap` describes an object of services corresponding to these DTO types.

And `DataType<K>` is a *distributive object type* such that `DataType<keyof DtoMap>` is a union similar to your original `DataType` type (except that we don't need `service` to live here; we can just write a `services` object of type `ServiceMap` instead).  If you pass a single key as `K`, you get just that member of the `DataType` union.

Now we can make `serviceManager()` generic in `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the keys of `DtoMap`:

```
serviceManager<K extends keyof DtoMap>(val: DataType<K>) {
  const services: ServiceMap = {
    car: this.carService,
    user: this.userService
  }
  const func = services[val.data];
  func.create(val.dto);
}
```

The `val` input is of type `DataType<K>`, meaning that `val.data` will determine which of the union members the call pertains to.  The `services` object is provably of type `ServiceMap`, and so `const func = services[val.data]` is seen as the generic type `{ create(val: DtoMap[K]): string }`.  And that means `func.create` is of type `(val: DtoMap[K]) => string`.  Since `val.dto` is of type `DtoMap[K]`, that means you are allowed to call `func.create(val.dto)`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOARALge2gbwFDWmAwDsI0kBXYTJACmLAFsEAuaMpAS2IHMBKHPgLQ0AC04QAdA2bQAvNBkIhAXyEAHCgCMQnYIqat25bjwDcuNblCQYAYTCpMggkVLkqNWlqRhiAEzYOUwE8YRFxKR8-f3loaIDVDW1dfQTA4y5eCysbKDhEJABlZAA3PQQXQiQEMDQEWlKwEDZ4ZHQMUKECAHoe6DsausqxSopC7ugatAokYmgAcgAzDAwFiwI1XPB8h2KyiqrgIfrG5rY9jq7wvoGTkdFK4EdJ6dn5ha1HdaSrbnqkEswMBKh0ALJgdRVcbIVqFDoAGiEzyQF0cHUsuFwaAAnupKiUkOUQRCoXIhNhoABtADS0G40AA1ggcRgltBwZCALpsSnHWqnJotDmYUm0rl8IImXjQFSyrG4-EcupgAAqeIQAB46QgAB71AIwZms9mc9QAPjilKpAAV6fMaTyKdB-Cq2DaES7MGwzbaufKVOKsdYdjAIdxCcTKmFCCQOJ4MHRJuouE16tAYfsiRU4chIxUkeEU5w009HPmQWis1HC9BQvKhIUoxCGDxkNroHqDf4jSy2SKMKTzWdhSgVer8drzddhG4yOwDiCIGwKwhSVbJq5HGwxBJJCjV7Xwpmd5FJJnV5M1OE52hoEsKMR9AomxUIFShZJXWgwFyNsIHyffd7hHL9MD4f8tmDW92DiYgEAAd2gcNiFXehEIKPNFwaPhPXgpC9jQvgIOsOM7yQOIpFfEk-DANs6Gwb8wDYAAiFEWM9fxvUUDDLkwWgWLALRgBYvgVBIoA)